# Finding the source file for a 500 Internal Service Error

Tags: linux

I am making changes to a server that was built by someone other than myself. I need to edit some information that is being displayed when a 500 Internal Service Error is generated, but I can't seem to find where to do that. It's a linux server.

Does anyone know of a process to determine where it is pointing to? I don't know what would cause the error to generate in the first place.

Comment: you should add some more info here. what kind of server is it? apache, nginx, lighttpd? depending on this you should look at the config files (usually in /etc/apache2, /etc/nginx and so on) and the error log to determine the cause of the error (somewhere in /var/log/apache2 or /var/log/nginx)

Comment: The problem was that the thing I was editing was "supposed" to be a 500 error page, but it was something else entirely, so my question is no longer valid. Can't seem to find a way to remove it though.